# Angularjs Return Json Dummy Data

Tags: json, angularjs

I am currently working with JSON with angularjs. I have created some JSON dummy variables. I have a for loops and I want to display 100 item (I set some of the data random).
I know what I am doing, but I just don't know how to display them. Help will be appreciated

I got the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hd7bc7ao/2/). This is how I am trying to display them

```
<div ng-repeat=" item in tempData">
    {{item.selectedOwner}}
</div>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle actually don't work because your have no angular module, no angular controller and neither used them in the html part. To use the ng-repeat you need to do ng-repeat="aJsObject in myJsObjectCollection" and access the property like this : "{{aJsObject.myproperty}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should put a lot more effort on your question.
Secondly, you had a lot of syntax error and didn't declared any angular module, any angular controller and neither added angular.

Here is a solution (in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FbkWFJ43LgjwCgQ2rkKH?p=preview)) for you with a little explanation about ng-repeat :

```
//To make the value accessible in the view you need to declare it in the controller scope.
$scope.tempData = [];

//You push all you test data in it.
$scope.tempData.push({
        id: i,
        owner: selectedOwner.text,
        modifiedDate: someDate.getDate(i),
        receiptDate: someDate.getDate(i),
        claimType: selectedClaimType.text,
        amount: i * 99,
        status: selectedStatus.text,
        customerName: selectedCustomer.text,

    })
```

And for displaying the collection :

```
<div ng-repeat="data in tempData">{{data.owner}} - {{data.customerName}} - {{data.claimType}}</div>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: sorry for the confusion of the question. I am still a little confused about angulajs because i started to learn it couple days ago. Thank you for your help. It is exactly what i want. peace

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not mad or anything, i just wanted to warn you. If you provide this quality of question you'll probably have no answer. You need to show us what you tried and provide a bit "cleaner" exemple.

Comment: What if I want to convert it to a list view, when I clicked on one of the100 items in that list, it will display that item's detail according to its id? How will you do that? like this one http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/isfAJ

Comment: @Anonymous when you use the ng-repeat syntax "object in collections" (for exemple) within this HTML element you can refert to each object with "object". When you can to show a property you do "object.property" so if you want to get the object on a click you just need to use a function that take in parameters. Like ng-click="doSomething(object)". Then in the $scope.doSomething function you will have this object and can interact with :) !